# Axios interceptors and asynchronous login

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, promise, axios

I'm implementing token authentication. My `access token` expires every N minutes and then a `refresh token` is used to log in and get a new `access token`.

I use Axios for my API calls. I have an interceptor set up to intercept `401` responses:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
  if (err.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
    serviceRefreshLogin(
      getRefreshToken(),
      success => { setTokens(success.access_token, success.refresh_token) },
      error => { console.log('Refresh login error: ', error) }
    )
    err.config.__isRetryRequest = true
    err.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
    return axios(err.config);
  }
  throw err
})
```

Basically, as I intercept a 401 response, I want to do a login and then retry the original rejected request with the new tokens. My `serviceRefreshLogin` function calls `setAccessToken()` in its `then` block. But the problem is that
the `then` block happens later than the `getAccessToken()` in the interceptor, so the retry happens with the old expired credentials.

`getAccessToken()` and `getRefreshToken()` simply return the existing tokens stored in the browser (they manage localStorage, cookies, etc).

How would I go about ensuring statements do not execute until a promise returns?

(Here's a corresponding issue on Github: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/266)

Answer (score 33):

Just use another promise :D

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (err.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
            serviceRefreshLogin(
                getRefreshToken(),
                success => { 
                        setTokens(success.access_token, success.refresh_token) 
                        err.config.__isRetryRequest = true
                        err.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken();
                        axios(err.config).then(resolve, reject);
                },
                error => { 
                    console.log('Refresh login error: ', error);
                    reject(error); 
                }
            );
        }
        throw err;
    });
});
```

If your enviroment doesn't suport promises use polyfill, for example https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

But, it may be better to rewrite getRefreshToken to return promise and then make code simpler

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (err) {

        if (err.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
            return getRefreshToken()
            .then(function (success) {
                setTokens(success.access_token, success.refresh_token) ;                   
                err.config.__isRetryRequest = true;
                err.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken();
                return axios(err.config);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Refresh login error: ', error);
                throw error;
            });
        }
        throw err;
});
```

Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZLpc8jgKI18w4c0f905?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as an interceptor. When I try this, the request gets retried only AFTER the original promise gets rejected.

Comment: Sorry, added a clarification - I don't see much sense in making getRefreshToken() into a promise. It's a function that manages stuff local to the browser - there is always something available there. Refresh token never expires BTW.

Comment: just a quick note, for me err.status is undefined, used err.response.status instead

Answer (score 15):

Could do it in the request instead of the response, and it'd probably be cleaner since it'd avoid hitting the server when the access token's expired. Copying from [this article](https://medium.com/@mateioprea/maintaining-api-authentication-using-axios-e70ba174da6):

```js
function issueToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return client({
      ...
    }).then((response) => {
      resolve(response);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

client.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  let originalRequest = config;
  if (tokenIsExpired && path_is_not_login) {
    return issueToken().then((token) => {
      originalRequest['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      return Promise.resolve(originalRequest);
    });
  }
  return config;
}, (err) => {
  return Promise.reject(err);
});
```