# How to handle ajax errors reusably with Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am building an SPA and I have a couple of different forms that submit data to an API. I am using `axios` for the ajax calls and have built a wrapper class around it for my use-case, called `api`. Inside that class I handle errors thrown by that instance.

The problem is I was storing an instance of the `api` class in each form's state. I later realized that functions shouldn't live in the state due to serialization.

The reasoning behind having the `api` class in the state was so that all of the children components of a form could access the errors and display their respective error along with removing the error on update.

One solution could be using an axios interceptor and commit all errors to a global errors module. But then I wouldn't know which errors belong to which form, in case two forms (or other requests) were submitted at the same time. I could of course save the errors in regard to the request URI, but then I would also have to take the request method into consideration.

```
reportError(state, { uri, method, errors }) {
  state.errors[uri + '@' + method] = errors;
}
```

Then I could have a getter like:

```
getErrorsByRequest: state => ({ uri, method }) => {
    return ...
}
```

But this feels unnecessarily awkward.

Since what I am trying to achieve is most likely very common, I am wondering, how do I sanely handle ajax errors reusably with Vuex?

Comment: You definitely should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247371/vue-js-nuxt-error-handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking for my old projects, and i did something similar:

This is my axios instance interceptor:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
  const { status } = error.response
  ...
  ...
  // data invalid (Unprocessable Entity)
  if (status === 422) {
    // errors list from response
    const dataErrors = error.response.data.errors
    let objErrors = {}

    // joining just the first error from array errors as value for each prop
    for (let key in dataErrors) {
      objErrors[key] = dataErrors[key].join()
    }

    // commiting to errors module
    store.commit('errors/SET_ERRORS', objErrors)
  }
  ...
  ...
})
```

Here my store module errors:

```
export const state = {
  form_errors: {}
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_ERRORS: (state, errors) => { state.form_errors = errors },

  CLEAN_ERRORS: (state) => { state.form_errors = {} }
}
```

Using on components:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState('errors', ['form_errors'])
}
```

Using on form template:

```
<q-input
  v-model="form.description"
  :error-message="form_errors.description"
  :error="!!form_errors.description"
/>
```