# How to get data from the backend that needs authorization using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, mern

I am creating a website using the `MERN` stack however I don't know how to get data to the frontend that needs authorization from the backend and I tried to console log the problem and it shows me the `HTML` of my login page even though I am logged in. Any will be appreciated thank you so much.

My backend code:

```
router.get("/questions", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    math = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    Security.findOne({
        user: req.user.id
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (math === 1) {
            res.send({
                question: user.firstQuestion
            });
        } else if (math === 2) {
            res.send({
                question: user.secondQuestion
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                question: user.thirdQuestion
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My Frontend code:

```
class QuestionForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/questions")
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.data
                });
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        return <h1 > {
            this.state.data
        } < /h1>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a lot of changes should be made.

1. you never want to use the port in your Axios request
   add to you `package.json` an proxy attribute

   `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`
   then you can change your axios get to

   `axios.get("/users/questions")`
2. best practice when using autorization is to add to axios **[interceptors](https://dev.to/teroauralinna/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor-30ae)**

follow this thread :
[How can you use axios interceptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737078/how-can-you-use-axios-interceptors)

and also here is an example for using authorization with [JWT token](https://jwt.io/)

```
const tokenHandler = axios.create();

tokenHandler.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = token;
  }
  return config;
});

export default tokenHandler;
```

let's say you create a token on the login page and store it inside your local storage.

now you can import the token handler and your request should look something like this :

```
import {tokenHandler} from '<TOKEN HANDLER PATH>'
..
..

 tokenHandler.get("/users/questions")
           .then((res)=>{
               this.setState({data:res.data});
           }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this implementation but the outcome is still the same.