# refresh JWT token when expire time is reached

Tags: react-native, axios, jwt

I'm working on a React native application and I need to set Authentication header on my sensitive requests.
But my accessToken (JWT) expires after 10 seconds. So before any request I have to check that if the token is expired renew it using a refreshToken **and then call last request again**.

I'm able to do all of these except last part (bold text).

And I'm using Axios for sending request to server.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea is to use a response interceptor that works after the response is available, but before it is passed down in the code.

It looks for `unauthenticated` error, which corresponds to statusCode 401

Keep in mind that this is a pseudo-code and You have to modify some parts like
`auth.setToken()`.

```
const createAxiosResponseInterceptor = () => {
  const interceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
      // Reject promise if not 401 error
      if (error.response.status !== 401) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      /*
       * When response code is 401, try to refresh the token.
       * Remove the interceptor so it doesn't loop in case
       * token refresh causes the 401 response
       *
       * Also eject the interceptor to prevent it from working again if the REFRESH request returns 401 too
       */
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(interceptor);

      return axios({
        url: API_REFRESH_URL,
        method: "POST",
        withCredentials: true,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          auth.setToken(response.data.access_token);
          error.response.config.headers["Authorization"] =
            "Bearer " + response.data.access_token;
          return axios(error.response.config);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          auth.removeToken();
          return Promise.reject(error);
        })
        .finally(createAxiosResponseInterceptor);
    }
  );
};

createAxiosResponseInterceptor();
```

`error.response.config` contains all the data about the old request so we can repeat it. Keep in mind that after completing the Refresh request we again apply the interceptor in `.finally(create...Interceptor)`

For more details please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737078/how-can-you-use-axios-interceptors), and official Docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)